# Is there a way to setup multiple Istio Gateways, each with same host, but in different namespaces?

Tags: istio

I've been following the post [here](https://istio.io/blog/2018/egress-mongo/#direct-tls-egress-traffic-through-an-egress-gateway) to setup a configuration to direct traffic from a Kubernetes cluster + Istio to an external service via an Istio egress gateway.

The setup I have is working fine - in isolation. However, I have 2 separate components (in separate Kubernetes namespaces) which I would like to be able to route traffic to the same external service. This means that I end up with a configuration where relevant Istio `Service Entries`, `Destination Rules`, `Virtual Services` and `Gateways` are duplicated in both namespaces. When I set this up, however, the `Gateway` resources appear to clash, and the egress gateway is not configured correctly, presumably because of the duplicate egress setup with the same host name and port combination. This stops either namespace from communicating with the external service.

I can fix this by removing one of the 'duplicate' `Gateway` resources, or by having only a single `Gateway` resource in a common namespace to control the egress. Neither of these options seems ideal to me though, as it essentially means that the configuration from one namespace is affecting the configuration of the other.

Am I missing something? (e.g. is there a way to setup the 'duplicate' configuration entirely within each namespace, without causing these problems - or is this just a situation where the Istio egress gateway is considered a 'shared' resource and requires configuration to be shared even across otherwise isolated namespaces?

Comment: I think it is possible to use single `gateway` and `serviceentry` for multiple namespaces. Once i verify it i will post an answer. What version of kubernetes and istio do you have?

Comment: Thanks @PiotrMalec - yes it's definitely possible - and that's the only way I can get it working currently. I'd prefer to be able to have these 'duplicated' in each namespace if it were possible without collisions though - I feel like it's keeps the namespace isolation better, particularly if you have different teams responsible for the different namespaces you're likely to end up with a lot of messing around trying to manage the 'shared' resources (and pain if they're changed/deleted unilaterally)

Comment: Hmm for that purpose it might be possible to go one step further and deploy second instance of istio in different namespace. This could be possible to do by generating istio manifest with `istioctl` saving it to file and then refactoring `istio-system` namespace to something like `istio-system2`. And finally applying to kubernetes.

Comment: @PiotrMalec That's an idea - although on a small cluster I'm not super-happy with the overhead of that. I guess an alternative would be a second istio egress gateway, or even an egress gateway per namespace. Again, seems like a bit of overhead though, and I was hoping there would be a way to just keep the configurations from stepping on each other's toes!

Comment: @Michael I have tried it few times back along with istio v1.1.3, but no success.